# Why is tsoutlier suggesting negative replacements in Sales Value time series?

Tags: r

I have a time series that contains daily sales values. I want to identify and replace the Outliers. However, the replacement suggestion contains negative amounts (at worst it can be only zero). The data series does not contain any negative amounts. Appreciate any help on this.

```html
> # Data for seriesComplete
> seriesComplete
Time Series:
Start = c(2019, 1) 
End = c(2022, 1) 
Frequency = 365 
[1] 1500.00 2600.00 2000.00 2700.00 3000.00 1700.00 1400.00 2300.00 2700.00 1900.00 2600.00 2900.00 1800.00 1400.00 2300.00 2000.00 2200.00 3200.00 3200.00 1500.00 1300.00 2600.00 2200.00 1800.00 2200.00 3500.00
[27] 1500.00 1500.00 2100.00 2100.00 2200.00 2000.00 2400.00 1400.00 1200.00 2100.00 2000.00 1900.00 2100.00 3100.00 1700.00 1100.00 2400.00 2300.00 1800.00 2100.00 3000.00 1300.00 1200.00 1900.00 2200.00 1700.00
[53] 2600.00 2200.00 1400.00 1200.00 1900.00 4000.00 3500.00 4200.00 6200.00 2200.00 1800.00 4600.00 3200.00 1800.00 2400.00 2000.00 1200.00 1200.00 2300.00 1700.00 1900.00 2300.00 2700.00 1500.00 1100.00 2000.00
[79] 2200.00 1400.00 2400.00 2200.00 1500.00 1000.00 1800.00 2085.91 1500.00 2085.91 2085.91 2085.91  900.00 2000.00 1800.00 1400.00 1800.00 2000.00 1200.00  900.00 1700.00 2000.00 1700.00 2000.00 2000.00 1300.00
[105]  800.00 1500.00 1800.00 1400.00 2200.00 2400.00 1400.00  800.00 3000.00 3200.00 3800.00 4400.00 5500.00 1200.00  800.00 2000.00 2100.00 2100.00 2500.00 2900.00 1700.00 2085.91 1900.00 2085.91 2100.00 2800.00
[131] 2600.00 2085.91 1000.00 2200.00 1800.00 2400.00 2100.00 3000.00 1700.00 1100.00 2100.00 2500.00 1600.00 2800.00 2900.00 1500.00 1400.00 2300.00 2100.00 1700.00 2300.00 2500.00 1800.00 1300.00 2200.00 2000.00
[157] 1900.00 2400.00 3100.00 1300.00 1200.00 2300.00 2300.00 1700.00 2600.00 2700.00 1300.00 1200.00 2300.00 2500.00 2100.00 2800.00 2200.00 2085.91 1300.00 2400.00 2400.00 2085.91 2600.00 2700.00 2000.00 1200.00
[183] 2300.00 2100.00 1700.00 2400.00 2600.00 1200.00 2400.00 4200.00 4100.00 3600.00 4200.00 5000.00 3200.00 2000.00 1800.00 2000.00 1900.00 2200.00 2400.00 1300.00  900.00 2000.00 1700.00 1700.00 2000.00 2600.00
[209] 1400.00 1100.00 2100.00 1800.00 1700.00 1800.00 2085.91 1000.00 1000.00 2085.91 1800.00 1300.00 2000.00 2000.00 1200.00 1100.00 2000.00 1700.00 1300.00 2085.91 2085.91 1300.00 2085.91 1500.00 1800.00 1700.00
[235] 2300.00 1900.00 1200.00  900.00 1800.00 1900.00 1300.00 2000.00 1900.00 1800.00 1100.00 2000.00 2000.00 2100.00 2300.00 3200.00 1400.00 1400.00 2500.00 2000.00 1800.00 2100.00 2300.00 1600.00 1300.00 2600.00
[261] 2500.00 1500.00 2100.00 2900.00 1700.00 1400.00 1900.00 1800.00 1900.00 2300.00 2900.00 1700.00 1200.00 2500.00 2000.00 2100.00 2400.00 2800.00 1700.00 1000.00 2400.00 1800.00 1600.00 2800.00 2300.00 1800.00
[287] 1300.00 1800.00 1700.00 2100.00 2400.00 3200.00 1800.00 1200.00 2400.00 2100.00 1900.00 2800.00 3200.00 1300.00 1300.00 1900.00 1800.00 2100.00 2600.00 2800.00 1700.00 1400.00 2200.00 2400.00 2100.00 3500.00
[313] 3300.00 2100.00 1700.00 2600.00 3000.00 2100.00 3100.00 3800.00 1600.00 1500.00 3000.00 2300.00 2400.00 3500.00 2900.00 1700.00 1500.00 2600.00 2600.00 2400.00 2600.00 3100.00 2000.00 1500.00 2300.00 2900.00
[339] 2400.00 2700.00 4100.00 2000.00 1800.00 2700.00 2300.00 2100.00 3400.00 3700.00 2200.00 1300.00 2700.00 2400.00 2000.00 3500.00 3100.00 4300.00 5200.00 6300.00    0.00    0.00 5500.00 5000.00 1600.00 1600.00
[365] 6200.00 1575.00 2262.00 2060.00 3159.00 2490.00 1428.00 1316.00 1840.00 2295.00 1729.00 2886.00 3074.00 1512.00 1512.00 2070.00 2400.00 1848.00 2976.00 3104.00 1590.00 1209.00 2964.00 2178.00 1818.00 2156.00
[391] 4165.00 1755.00 1395.00 1848.00 1974.00 2222.00 1740.00 2736.00 1456.00 1236.00 2079.00 1900.00 1786.00 2058.00 2666.00 1564.00 1243.00 2040.00 2185.00 1944.00 1890.00 2490.00 1092.00 1032.00 1862.00 2046.00
[417] 1904.00 3016.00 2618.00 1414.00 1176.00 1824.00 3480.00 3080.00 4116.00 5766.00 2420.00 2160.00 5014.00 3360.00 1458.00 2808.00 2020.00 1248.00 1296.00 1932.00 1989.00 1729.00 2438.00 2376.00 1245.00 1089.00
[443] 2040.00 2640.00 1148.00 1968.00 2464.00 1260.00  860.00 1674.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00  783.00 2080.00 2106.00 1652.00 2088.00 1940.00 1344.00 1053.00 1479.00 2280.00 1360.00 2040.00 2000.00
[469] 1391.00  744.00 1545.00 1890.00 1386.00 2090.00 2184.00 1680.00  744.00 3090.00 2688.00 4522.00 3784.00 6270.00 1320.00  792.00 1780.00 2310.00 2100.00    0.00 2494.00 1751.00    0.00 1824.00    0.00 2037.00
[495] 2716.00 2522.00    0.00  910.00 2310.00 1584.00    0.00 1848.00 2460.00 1870.00 1067.00 2016.00 2875.00 1872.00 3052.00 2697.00 1410.00 1540.00 1840.00 1995.00 1377.00 2484.00 2975.00 1728.00 1105.00 1980.00
[521] 1960.00 2033.00 2808.00 2573.00 1287.00 1308.00 2622.00 2369.00 1564.00 2548.00 2484.00 1365.00 1236.00 2093.00 2225.00 2478.00 2240.00 2464.00    0.00 1456.00 2424.00 2016.00    0.00 2522.00 2754.00    0.00
[547] 1224.00 1978.00 2310.00 1785.00 2664.00 2366.00  960.00 2736.00 3444.00 4182.00 3348.00 3906.00 4600.00 3520.00 2140.00 1746.00 2240.00 1995.00 2046.00 2208.00 1066.00  945.00 2360.00 1360.00 1734.00 1680.00
[573] 2990.00 1204.00  891.00 2499.00 1512.00 1479.00 1890.00    0.00  900.00 1200.00    0.00 1566.00 1144.00 1960.00 1740.00 1260.00 1243.00 2240.00 1615.00 1443.00    0.00    0.00 1339.00    0.00 1695.00 1440.00
[599] 1683.00 2277.00 1520.00 1032.00  945.00 1728.00 2071.00 1547.00 2200.00 1729.00 1458.00 1309.00 2320.00 1780.00 2457.00 2438.00 2688.00 1288.00 1218.00 2450.00 2000.00 2160.00 2142.00 2737.00 1296.00 1118.00
[625] 2340.00 2525.00 1785.00 1974.00 2407.00 1445.00 1470.00 2033.00 1926.00 2052.00 2553.00 3248.00 1836.00 1176.00 2025.00 1760.00 2058.00 2160.00 2324.00 1751.00  840.00 2880.00 1602.00 1664.00 3024.00 2392.00
[651] 1818.00 1261.00 1440.00 1887.00 1932.00 2856.00 3392.00 1728.00 1260.00 2472.00 1995.00 2242.00 3192.00 3392.00 1495.00 1300.00 1672.00 1980.00 1806.00 2184.00 3332.00 1530.00 1470.00 2222.00 2568.00 2478.00
 [677] 4025.00 3630.00 1680.00 1700.00 2626.00 2460.00 2310.00 3565.00 3382.00 1328.00 1560.00 3300.00 2185.00 1992.00 3430.00 2697.00 1394.00 1605.00 3094.00 2964.00 2208.00 2158.00 2914.00 1940.00 1395.00 2093.00
 [703] 3103.00 2880.00 2565.00 3403.00 2140.00 1872.00 2214.00 2162.00 2499.00 3094.00 3108.00 2376.00 1183.00 2160.00 1968.00 2040.00 4130.00 2635.00 3913.00 4940.00 7245.00    0.00    0.00 4895.00 4350.00 1440.00
 [729] 1392.00 5642.00 1755.00 2678.00 1860.00 2457.00 2430.00 1632.00 1666.00 2737.00 2349.00 1558.00 2444.00 2552.00 1998.00 1232.00 2139.00 2040.00 2420.00 3328.00 3552.00 1695.00 1404.00 2392.00 1914.00 1458.00
 [755] 1760.00 3430.00 1605.00 1395.00 2373.00 2457.00 2134.00 2180.00 2760.00 1344.00 1368.00 2163.00 2320.00 1710.00 2058.00 3720.00 1496.00  946.00 2376.00 2415.00 2142.00 2352.00 2700.00 1040.00 1404.00 1520.00
 [781] 2068.00 1700.00 2834.00 1848.00 1484.00 1368.00 1767.00 4720.00 3115.00 4116.00 5394.00 2486.00 1566.00 5198.00 3040.00 1782.00 2136.00 1860.00 1020.00 1404.00 2208.00 1666.00 1539.00 2553.00 2457.00 1350.00
 [807] 1122.00 2160.00 2574.00 1498.00 2472.00 2552.00 1200.00 1140.00 1692.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00 1026.00 1860.00 1980.00 1526.00 2034.00 1860.00 1068.00  756.00 1768.00 2380.00 1887.00 1760.00
 [833] 1940.00 1092.00  784.00 1245.00 1944.00 1414.00 2552.00 2280.00 1456.00  848.00 2400.00 3328.00 3268.00 3872.00 4400.00 1212.00  672.00 1600.00 1995.00 1995.00    0.00 3451.00 1581.00    0.00 1672.00    0.00
 [859] 2394.00 3108.00 2392.00    0.00  910.00 2442.00 1674.00    0.00 2226.00 2940.00 1479.00 1067.00 2121.00 2125.00 1696.00 2688.00 2900.00 1200.00 1498.00 2461.00 2520.00 1598.00 2093.00 2725.00 2034.00 1378.00
 [885] 2332.00 1720.00 1520.00 2808.00 3596.00 1326.00 1104.00 2070.00 2047.00 1836.00 3016.00 2781.00 1560.00 1308.00 2093.00 2675.00 2373.00 2576.00 2420.00    0.00 1508.00 1992.00 2616.00    0.00 2366.00 2727.00
 [911]    0.00 1440.00 2162.00 2100.00 1598.00 2664.00 2886.00 1164.00 2184.00 4872.00 3854.00 3024.00 4074.00 5350.00 3456.00 1920.00 1746.00 2240.00 1615.00 1804.00 2784.00 1495.00  945.00 2240.00 1513.00 1683.00
 [937] 1740.00 2262.00 1554.00  913.00 2310.00 1674.00 2040.00 1710.00    0.00  840.00 1050.00    0.00 1638.00 1495.00 1860.00 2140.00 1044.00 1122.00 2180.00 1887.00 1170.00    0.00    0.00 1430.00    0.00 1380.00
 [963] 1890.00 2023.00 1978.00 1919.00 1140.00 1017.00 1944.00 1729.00 1508.00 2100.00 1672.00 2034.00 1254.00 2140.00 1780.00 1680.00 1909.00 2912.00 1302.00 1400.00 2350.00 1960.00 2034.00 2037.00 1978.00 1584.00
 [989] 1274.00 2600.00 2675.00 1485.00 2205.00 3306.00 1921.00 1498.00 1672.00 2088.00 2261.00 2461.00
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 96 entries ]



> #To identify Outliers
> tsoutliers(seriesComplete,lambda = NULL)

# Outliers Identified and Suggested Replacements

$index
 [1]   86   87   88   89   90  117  123  126  128  132  136  174  178  181  190  215  218  228  229
[20]  231  348  369  391  419  479  480  482  507  555  573  622  671  677  684  695  704  706  719
[39]  723  726  727  738  770  788  843  847  854  889  920  924  978 1008 1028 1050 1055 1077 1087
[58] 1092

$replacements
 [1]   78.22813   66.12149   54.01485   41.90821   29.80157 1959.87276  132.56774   68.94140
 [9]   41.86467   86.16884   87.55093 -137.95860   18.46241  -40.54954 2221.23595   50.01694
[17]   34.14786  -12.93001  -28.96279  -28.27826 3046.58510 2530.69312 3550.21256 2207.43635
[25] 3273.68369 3290.78752 1706.99371 2046.21552 2430.76625 2280.94205 1919.63368 2523.41364
[33] 3758.50769 3000.09525 2481.96942 2390.35107 4323.17411 3206.85777 6461.10538 5512.65411
[41] 2400.26476 2228.56276 2812.12186 3495.25407 3099.02148 1692.11466 2626.73434 2610.45045
[49] 1991.29655 4808.65691 2039.27194 2341.77677 2852.88960 3633.92384 2171.39376 3215.05549
[57] 5217.40587 2552.92493
```

Comment: Please provide data, not pictures of data. The latter does not help us answer your question.

Comment: hi @jlhoward I have provided (hopefully) the information you requested. Thanks.

Comment: I'd need the original time series `seriesComplete` (not just the summary) to really diagnose this, but I see the minimum value is 0. `tsoutliers(...)` will apply a seasonal decomposition to detect ol. Assuming the 0's are outliers, it is not unreasonable to think that this algorithm would produce imputed values < 0.

Comment: I have inserted the data for seriesComplete as requested. Yes it's not unreasonable for 0's to be an outlier, however given that the data is Sales value, how do I limit it to only consider the upper outliers and not go below 0?

Comment: The data you provided was workable but not complete. For future reference, it is much better if you post the output of `dput(seriesComplate)`.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is specifically: why does `tsoutlier(...)` produce  negative recommendations in a sales dataset? The glib response is that `tsoutlier(...)` does not know or care that this is sales data.

Having said that, here is a possible alternative (using `data.table` for convenience).

```
library(data.table)
library(forecast)
library(ggplot2)
tsData <- data.table(ts=seriesComplete)
tsData[, date:=seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'), len=.N, by=1)]
tsData[, ts.na:=ts]
tsData[ts.na==0, ts.na:=NA]
tsData[, ts.clean:=tsclean(ts)]
tsData[, ts.na.clean:=tsclean(ts.na)]
gg.melt <- melt(tsData, measure.vars = c('ts', 'ts.clean', 'ts.na', 'ts.na.clean'))
ggplot(gg.melt, aes(x=date, y=value))+
  geom_line(aes(color=variable))+
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)+
  scale_color_discrete(name=NULL, guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6)))+
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

[image]

The basic idea here is that, if you know 0 sales is some kind of error (missing data, perhaps?), then set to `NA` and use `tsclean(...)` on the result. The top plot (red) is your data. The second is the result of `tsclean(...)` on the raw data - not great. The third is your data with the 0s replaced with `NA` (you can't see it in this tiny plot but if you run this yourself you'll see the gaps). The bottom plot (violet) is the result of `tsclean(..)` on the `ts.na` column.

You can tell just from looking at the plots that this is a multi-seasonal time series (periods 7 and 365). If you pass an `msts` object to `tsclean(...)` you get a slightly different (better??) result.

```
tsData[, ts.msts.clean:=tsclean(msts(ts.na, seasonal.periods = c(7, 365)))]
gg.melt <- melt(tsData, measure.vars = c('ts', 'ts.na.clean', 'ts.msts.clean'))
ggplot(gg.melt, aes(x=date, y=value))+
  geom_line(aes(color=variable))+
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)+
  scale_color_discrete(name=NULL, guide=guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=6)))+
  facet_grid(variable~.)
```

[image]

Finally, I notice that you had a strong burst of sales around Thanksgiving 2021 but not the other two years. "Cleaning" the data gets rid of that, which might not be what you want. It's all down to what you plan to do with the (cleaned) data.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation @jlhoward.  I am quite new to r and still working my way through it. I'm grateful that you took the time and effort to systematically break it down. Best regards.